# Nested form with has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to make a nested form,
my form is for model A which have many Bs, and have to save them all on the save form.
The problem is: I'm building 3 bs on A controller, but only one field is showing up,
here's the code:

class A:

```
class A < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bs
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :bs
end
```

class B:

```
class B < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :a
end
```

A controller:

```
class AController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @a = A.new
    3.times { @a.bs.build }
  end
end
```

A and B form:

```
<%= form_for :a do |f| %>
   <%= f.fields_for :bs do |b| %>
    <%= b.text_field :name, :class => 'default' %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<%= form_for @a do |f| %>
   <%= f.fields_for :bs do |b| %>
    <%= b.text_field :name, :class => 'default' %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

`@a`, not `:a`